# Can't find React HTML elements reference width and height

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reference

After a while messing with my code I don't seem to be able to find the width of an HTML element using the React `createRef` solution. Below you can see the constructor and how I'm initializing the reference.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.elementToTrack = React.createRef();
}
```

After this, I'm creating the reference on the object I'm wanting to track the size of.

```js
<tr>
    <th ref={this.elementToTrack} className="upperHeader">Location</th>
</tr>
```

At this point, if I was to console the ref it would display the React element/DOM element I'm not entirely sure. but from this, I'm unsure how I'm meant to access its current size properties.

I've tried the suggestions below with no luck:

```js
this.elementToTrack.current.offsetWidth;
this.elementToTrack.current.width;
this.elementToTrack.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Comment: Should be `getComputedStyle(this.elementToTrack.current).width` (you need to do this in case you didn't hard-code a width). Also, once you do `console.log(this.elementToTrack.current)` and get the element, this ceases to be a React question.

Comment: Looks like this did work I was doing something stupid with it but now its on the correct element it can find the value.

Comment: In that case it should be `this.elementToTrack.current.getBoundingClientRect().width`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using refs, you can use simple javascript's `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` properties. Give id attribute to your `th` like this:

```
<tr>
    <th ref={this.elementToTrack} id="sampleID" className="upperHeader">Location</th>
</tr>


var width = document.getElementById('sampleID').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('sampleID').offsetHeight;
```

this will return you the current width and height of the tag. Hope that works well with you..